# Assume that $ 1a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n=1$, where the $a_j$ are real numbers.

Tags: geometry, inequality

Assume that
$$
1a_1+2a_2+\cdots+na_n=1,
$$
where the $a_j$ are real numbers.
As a function of $n$, what is the minimum value of
$$1a_1^2+2a_2^2+\cdots+na_n^2?$$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. When you ask a question here, you will get the best response if you also say what you know about the question, what you have attempted, where you got stuck, and so on. Otherwise, people who wish to help you may be wasting their time in various ways such as explaining what you already know.

Comment: ${2 \over n\,\left(\,n + 1\,\right)}$.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $1 = \left(1a_1+\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}a_2)+\cdots + \sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n}a_n)\right)^2\leq (1+2+\cdots + n)(1a_1^2+2a_2^2+\cdots + na_n^2)$

Comment: (Cauchy Schwarz)

Answer (score 0):

From Jensen's inequality, the weighted average of the squares is greater than or equal to the square of the weighted average.

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? $1a_1 ^2 + \dots + na_n^2 \leq (1a_1 + \dots + na_n)^2$?

Comment: Remember, the sum of the weights must equal one, so you need to scale the expressions.

Comment: I'm unaware of the inequality, just trying to interpret what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets
>   $\ds{\mathbf{r} \equiv\pars{\substack{\ds{a_{1}} \\ \ds{\vdots} \\[1mm] \ds{a_{n}}}}}$,
>   
> $\ds{\mathsf{A}}$ is a diagonal matrix with eigenvalues $\ds{\braces{i}}$ $\ds{\pars{i = 1,2,\ldots,n}}$ and
>   $\ds{\mathbf{u} \equiv
> \pars{\substack{\ds{1} \\[2mm] \ds{2} \\[2mm] \ds{\vdots} \\[2mm] \ds{n}}}}$.

The problem is reduced to find the minimum of $\ds{{\Large\varepsilon} \equiv \mathbf{r}^{\mrm{T}}\mathsf{A}\mathbf{r}}$ under the restriction $\ds{\mathbf{r}^{\mrm{T}}\mathbf{u} = 1}$. The *Lagrange Multiplier Method* yields

\begin{align}
&\mathsf{A}\mathbf{r} - \lambda\mathbf{u} = 0\,,\qquad
\pars{~\lambda:\ Lagrange\ Multiplier~}
\\
\implies &
\mathbf{r} = \lambda\mathsf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{u} =
\lambda
\pars{\substack{\ds{1} \\[2mm] \ds{1} \\[2mm] \ds{\vdots} \\[2mm] \ds{1}}}
\implies
1 = \lambda \pars{1 + 2 + \cdots + n} \implies \lambda = {2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}
\\[5mm] \implies &
\mathbf{r} = 
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\,\pars{\substack{\ds{1} \\[2mm] \ds{1} \\[2mm] \ds{\vdots} \\[2mm] \ds{1}}}
\\[5mm] \implies &
{\Large\varepsilon} = {2 \over n\pars{n + 1}}\,\pars{1 + 2 + \cdots + n}\,
{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}} = \bbx{2 \over n\pars{n + 1}} 
\end{align}